# Declaring and changing class instances inside another class

Tags: python, class, instance, instance-variables, member-variables

Hello fine people of Stackoverflow!

I have a problem. I am trying to change an instance variable (which is on it's own a class instance) and for some reason, it changes the same instance variable for all instances of the original class.

here is the code:

```
#create State class
class State(object):

    awake = False

#Set Person Class
class Person(object):

    state = State()
    
#create person instences
jack = Person()
jill = Person()


print(jack.state.awake)
print(jill.state.awake)

#wake jill only
jill.state.awake = True

print("")
print(jack.state.awake)
print(jill.state.awake)
```

OUTPUT:

```
False
False

True
True
```

I am trying to wake jill only.

Comment: `awake` is not an instance attribute. It's on the class itself.

Comment: what does that mean? like, how can I fix this so that it works?

Answer (score 1):

For `awake` and `state` to be instance variables they'd have to be bound to a `self` instance, instead of at the class level. Otherwise class variables are static, in other words share state across all instances of that class.

```
class State:
    def __init__(self):
        self.awake = False

class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = State()
```

Then it works as you described

```
>>> jack = Person()
>>> jill = Person()
>>> jack.state.awake
False
>>> jill.state.awake
False
>>> jill.state.awake = True
>>> jack.state.awake
False
>>> jill.state.awake
True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#create State class
class State(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.awake = False

#Set Person Class
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = State()
    
#create person instences
jack = Person()
jill = Person()


print(jack.state.awake)
print(jill.state.awake)

#wake jill only
jill.state.awake = True

print("")
print(jack.state.awake)
print(jill.state.awake)
```